# Why array.filter return "ABCDE'' and "UHY"

Tags: javascript

iam doing my project and suddenly i found this problem but don't know why.
I have array:

```
arr=['ABCDE','HOANG','UHY']
```

then i use

```
arr.filter(x=>x.indexOf('H'))
```

the result will be `(2) ["ABCDE", "UHY"]`

Comment: truthy check...... look up a truth table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial code will not work properly because `indexOf` returns an integer with the index of the letter you passed as parameter, and not a boolean if it's present or not in your string:

```js
console.log('ABCDE'.indexOf('H')); // -1 (means true)
console.log('HOANG'.indexOf('H')); // 0 (means false)
console.log('UHY'.indexOf('H')); // 1
```

To avoid this, you must compare the result of `indexOf` with NOT `-1`:

```js
var arr = ['ABCDE','HOANG','UHY'];

var result = arr.filter(x=> x.indexOf('H') !== -1);

console.log(result);
```

If you are using [ECMAScript 6](http://es6-features.org/), you can use the [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) since it returns a boolean instead of the index number. (thanks to @Vidushan Chooriyakumaran for the suggestion)

```js
const arr = ['ABCDE','HOANG','UHY'];

const result = arr.filter(x=> x.includes('H'));

console.log(result);
```

Note that since I'm assuming ES6 here, I'm also using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

Comment: If ES6 is used, you can also use `x => x.includes('H')` which is shorter.

Comment: Nice, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Also, 'HOANG' is not returned because it starts with 'H', so indexOf returns 0 (which is the position of 'H' in the string) and 0 is not truthy.

Answer (score 1):

When index of doesn't find a matching element (the letter H in this case) it returns `-1`. As `-1` is truthy value `!!-1 === true` the the 1st item is not filtered out. However, the H letter is the 1st item in HOANG (index 0), and `!!0 === false`.

Filter out items for which `indexOf` returns `-1`:

```js
const arr=['ABCDE','HOANG','UHY']

const result = arr.filter(x=>x.indexOf('H') !== -1)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: so it use !! to convert a non-booleen value to booleen right

Comment: The `!!` is an example of what happens when you cast a value to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` will return `-1` when there is no match. Use `includes` instead.

```js
const arr = ['ABCDE','HOANG','UHY'];
const result = arr.filter(x => x.includes('H'));
console.log(result);
```